# How to unify string column values based on unique Id in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to unify data frame column values based on unique id

Input :

```
import pandas as pd

    d = {'code' : pd.Series(['VC_1', 'VC_1', 'BN_3','BN_4'] ),
       'value' : pd.Series(['LTC Limited', 'LTC LTD', 'AMZ ENT', 'BBM CROP'])}
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    print (df)


   code        value
0  VC_1  LTC Limited
1  VC_1      LTC LTD
2  BN_3      AMZ ENT
3  BN_4     BBM CROP
```

Expected output:

```
code        value
0  VC_1  LTC Limited
1  VC_1  LTC Limited
2  BN_3      AMZ ENT
3  BN_4     BBM CROP
```

Here in value column want to unify with first occurrence of name or with any one name for the entire unique combination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this,

```
df['value'] = df.groupby(['code'])['value'].transform('first')
```

---

```
   code        value
0  VC_1  LTC Limited
1  VC_1  LTC Limited
2  BN_3      AMZ ENT
3  BN_4     BBM CROP
```